# ASP.NET Core JWT authentication changes Claims (sub)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have an ASP.NET Core API which uses JWT Authentication. Simple setup:

```
....
string authority = $"https://{configuration["Auth:Authority"]}";
string audience = configuration["Auth:Audience"];

return builder.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.Authority = authority;
    options.Audience = audience;

    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        // NameClaimType = "http://schemas.org/email"
        // NameClaimType = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/email"
        // NameClaimType = "sub"
    };
});
```

(as you can see commented code, I have been trying several settings)

When I decode JWT (using jwt.io) I see there is claim "sub" in JWT and has string value (internal ID of user in dbo)

```
{
  "nbf": 1592585433,
  "exp": 1592585763,
  "iss": "https://*************",
  "aud": "api_10",
  "sub": "142",
  "scope": [
    "openid",
    "api_10"
  ]
}
```

The problem is that dotnet switch sub to name claim. This returns no (0) results:

`principal.Claims.Where(w => w.Type == "sub")`

This returns userId I need "142":

`principal.Claims.Where(w => w.Type == ClaimTypes.Name || ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)`

What is going on?! Where is my sub claim gone?

Comment: You probably need the line `JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();`. Please please read [this article](https://leastprivilege.com/2017/11/15/missing-claims-in-the-asp-net-core-2-openid-connect-handler/) for more explanation.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just add `JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();` on the API's `ConfigureServices` method. Its suggested on the other comment as well. I verified it on my [sample repo](https://github.com/nahidf-adventures/IdentityServer4-adventures/blob/master/src/CoreApi/Startup.cs#L23).

This issue is because [OIDC StandardClaims](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#StandardClaims) are renamed on JWT token handler. By adding `JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();` you will clear the inbound claim type map on the JWT token handler.

Read more [here](https://leastprivilege.com/2017/11/15/missing-claims-in-the-asp-net-core-2-openid-connect-handler/)

Comment: Also, this will fix it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68253821/98802

Comment: Just had this same issue myself. Many thanks for the question and solution.

Comment: This no longer works in .NET 8. Haven't been able to verify why exactly...

Comment: In .NET 8 it has changed to "JsonWebTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap" and you need "using Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens" to bring it into scope.

Answer (score 2):

In .NET 8 you simply set the `MapInboundOptions` field of the `JwtBearerOptions` to `false`.

For Example:

```
services
  .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  .AddJwtBearer(o => {
    o.MapInboundClaims = false;
    …
  }
```